# Observable which runs Runnables received in onNext on main thread with delay between items

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java

I want to have Observable which runs `Runnable`s received in onNext on main thread with delay between items (in my snippet it's 2 seconds).

So far I have:

```
Subscription xxx = Observable
    .create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Runnable>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Runnable> subscriber) {
            gate = subscriber;
        }
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .subscribe(new Action1<Runnable>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Runnable runnable) {
            Log.d(TAG, "call " + Thread.currentThread().toString());
            runnable.run();
        }
    });
```

Then something somewhere at some thread calls the `gate` instance's `onNext` method like:

```
Log.d(TAG, "gate requested on thread " + Thread.currentThread().toString());
gate.onNext(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d(TAG, "make it on thread " + Thread.currentThread().toString());
    }
});
```

But ... it does not work as I wanted. What I wanted is: `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` was suppose to run Runnables on main thread; but it's run on "RxComputationScheduler-2".

I get output like:

```
gate requested on thread Thread[Binder_2,5,main]
gate call Thread[RxComputationScheduler-2,5,main]
gate make on thread Thread[RxComputationScheduler-2,5,main]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

to:

```
.delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

Comment: Thanks it works, can you briefly explain WHY it solves my problem?

Comment: I think it's because http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/delay.html "By default this variant of delay operates on the computation Scheduler".

Comment: or even better `delay(2L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`